# Excel 2010 Chart with target lines and custom table

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts

I am trying to create a bar chart with the data table underneath and 3 target lines.

1. [Chart with target lines, no data underneath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBiZr.png)- Chart looks great, but I need the data

[image]

2. [Chart with no target lines, data underneath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeN4a.png) - Data looks great, but missing target lines.

[image]

3. [Chart with target lines, with data underneath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hl6Gb.png) - Data looks horrible but chart is great.

[image]

So what do I have to do to get the Chart to look like 1 or 3 and the table to look like 2?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is cheat!  Excel, and its default behaviour, won't accomplish what you've shown.

Instead of fighting Excel, just change how you're using it (a little).

1. Create a chart that looks like you want (e.g. image 1).
2. Layout your 3 rows of data that you want included.
3. Move your chart and align it over the data on your worksheet (Page Layout>Align>Snap to Grid helps alignment).
4. Format to taste.

[image: demo]

and using your original colors

[image]

Comment: Well, I could do that, I suppose. I was hoping for something a little more elegant...Thanks anyway.

Comment: I've found that Excel is more workhorse, less elegance.  That said, it can do almost anything-if not in the most straightforward way.  You could also look for a vba solution-but I've found those usually have poor roi value (but that's probably because I'm not a programmer).